# Tensorflow on Centos 6.6 requires GLIBCXX v 3.4.19+ of libstdc++.so.6

Tags: centos, gcc

Trying to get Tensorflow onto a Centos 6 Cloudera system which is **airgapped (offline)**. I've gotten just about all the dependencies working with `rpm` and offline packages. However, I am still snarled on the version of `libstdc++.so.6`.

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.3.2
```

I took [this advice](https://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos) to install gcc 4.8 however `find / -name libstdc++.so.6` does not reveal this specific .so file.

I suspect [I may have to compile GCC from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216399/usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found), and I really really do not want to do that, because I won't have any sysadmin over the client's system. I basically have to give them a disk with some files and it just has to work (it's a long story, the job is what it is). If anything fails, it'll be a long turnaround to figure out what went wrong.

Is there any way I can build the GCC locally and bundle it as an `.rpm`?

Here's the original error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found (required by /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so)
```

Comment: I wouldn't assume libs on your client's machine should be identical to your Cloudera system. Some may be hardware dependent. I'd want to at least check that first. [This discussion](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/483) may help you resolve the problem.

Comment: Yeah I can't assume that, either, but it's the best I can do for now. I'll check out that link, thanks!